# Active admin + sql server + composite_primary_keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I was trying to get sql server table into active admin, but that has composite primary keys,

Models

```
consult_record.rb
class ConsultRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection :"consult_#{Rails.env}"
  ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SQLServerAdapter.lowercase_schema_reflection = true
end


raw_punch.rb
require 'composite_primary_keys'
class RawPunch < ConsultRecord
  self.table_name = "[dbo].[MachineRawPunch]"
  self.primary_key = [:cardno, :officepunch]
end
```

Error - 
[browser error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3absX.png)

Query 
[query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/By5YP.png)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

According to [the README](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys#the-basics-) the syntax is `self.primary_keys = :cardno, :officepunch`